# Swap an page and put data (several images and links) in my listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone, html-agility-pack, swap, word-wrap

I need to get data from the website and put this data in my `Listbox` in Xaml. I'm using Windows Phone.

This is my c# function:

```
private void DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
            {
                ObservableCollection<PopularVideos> _popVideos = new ObservableCollection<PopularVideos>();
                var data = e.Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='content']")
                   .Descendants("img")
                   .Select(img => new PopularVideos()
                   {                   
                       Titulo = img.Attributes["alt"].Value,
                       Url = img.Attributes["src"].Value,                   
                   }).ToList();

                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
                {

                    foreach (var item in data)
                    {   
                        _popVideos.Add(new PopularVideos(item.Titulo, item.Url));
                    }
                });
            }
```

class `PopularVideos`:

```
public class PopularVideos
    {
        public PopularVideos() { }
        public PopularVideos(string titulo, string url)
        {
            Titulo = url;
            Url = url;            
        }

        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

`Listbox` in Xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxPopular" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" DataContext="{Binding}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Name="imagem" Source="{Binding Path=Url}"/>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Tap="HyperlinkButton_Tap"  FontSize="30" Foreground="#FF159DDE" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

This code shows no error, but my `Listbox` remains empty.

Source code in the main page codebehind:

```
namespace AppUnno
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        int aux = 3;
        private List<Artista> _artistas;


        public class MyDataContextClass
        {
            public ObservableCollection<PopularVideos> PopVideos;

            public MyDataContextClass()
            {
                ObservableCollection<PopularVideos> PopVideos = new ObservableCollection<PopularVideos>();
            }

            private void DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
            {
                PopVideos.Clear();
                // Add to pop Videos.
            }
        }

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                ConsultaArtista("http://www.unnu.com/music-artists");
                //ConsultaPopularVideos("http://www.unnu.com/popular-music-videos");
                panorama.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
                DataContext = App.ViewModel;
                this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);                
                carregaFeed();
                ApplicationBarra(aux);
                HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("http://www.unnu.com/popular-music-videos", DownLoadCompleted);
            }
            else
            {
                var result = MessageBox.Show("There are problems in your connection. Please verify your connection and try again!", "", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                aux = 1;
                ApplicationBarra(aux);
            }
        }
    private void DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
    {
        PopVideos.Clear();
        var data = e.Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='content']")
           .Descendants("img")
           .Select(img => new PopularVideos()
           {                   
               Titulo = img.Attributes["alt"].Value,
               Url = img.Attributes["src"].Value,                   
           }).ToList();

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
        {

            foreach (var item in data)
            {   
                PopVideos.Add(new PopularVideos(item.Titulo, item.Url));
            }
        });
    }
```

The errors is the "PopVideos" in the DownloadCompleted function:

*

> "The name 'PopVideos' does not exist in the current context"

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **Local variable instead of a property**:

```
    ObservableCollection<PopularVideos> _popVideos = new ObservableCollection<PopularVideos>();
```

The above line indicates that you are using a local variable, **any changes you make to it are gone with it by the end of the method**. You probably wanted to use a property of your class, but didn't.

You should:

1. Use a property of your class.
2. Have it be public (naming convention also suggests you call it PopVideos).
3. Have the binding in your Xaml be correctly defined, as well as the DataContext.
4. Keep the same instance of the Binded property, doing something like `PopVideos = new` after the constructor will result in the breaking of the binding.

**Code example for a possible solution:**

Since some of your code is missing, a simple example of how it should be:

**MyDataContextClass.cs:**

```
public class MyDataContextClass{
     public ObservableCollection<PopularVideo> PopVideos;

     public MyDataContextClass(){
          PopVideos = new ObservableCollection<PopularVideo>();
     }
     ...
     private void DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e){
         PopVideos.Clear();
         // Add to pop Videos.
     }
}
```

**MyXamlViewClass.Xaml.cs:**

It should have it's **DataContext** set to the relevant instance of `MyDataContextClass`, one way of doing it:

```
public class MyXamlViewClass : UserControl{ // could be a window, or whatever you are using.
    public MyXamlViewClass(MyDataContextClass vm){
        DataContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();//If I remember the method name correctly
    }
}
```

**MyXamlViewClass.Xaml:**

Make sure you bind to your `ObservableCollection` Properly:

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxPopular" ItemsSource="{Binding PopularVideos Mode=OneWay}">
    ...
```

**Edit (due to comment):**

This is how it should look (different name):

[image: .Xaml & .Xaml.cs]

Replace your relevant code with this one (make sure you change it properly):

MainPage.Xaml.cs : [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/5ty4imbc)

MainPage.Xaml : [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/KehQD7tH)

Comment: I've added an example for you to look at, also , adding more info will help focus the answer to a single source for the issue (entire class definition, view instantiaion code,etc.)

Comment: Thank you Bro! I will study it and now I pass you feedback here in the comments!

Comment: No problem , I've simplified the explanation in my latest edit, read it again if you have any issues.

Comment: I am very beginner and honestly can not implement parts of code. _popVideos.Clear Gave error and do not know where this class implement MyXamlViewClass. Please explain if you need to create a new class by adding another file to the project and also what is the MyDataContextClass

Comment: oh, ok! ignore my last comment.

Comment: I do not know where to put the last two blocks of code. Apart from that I understand what you're saying!

Comment: the file in which you have the ListView Xaml Definition => MyXamlViewClass.Xaml.
It should also have a MyXamlViewClass.Xaml.cs file, with C# code in it.

Comment: BTW - change `Titulo` to `Title` (or other way around), it doesn't match your Xaml definition.

Comment: Two blocks in the same file?

Comment: attached an image on how it should look.

Comment: I put all this within the file you said, but instances "PopularVideos" can not be accessed within the methods. Also you wrote "method DownloadCompleted" within the class that has the same as another.

Comment: I need to leave now, please do not abandon the topic, early tomorrow morning I'll come back. Thanks so far!

Comment: It is hard to tell how you code behaves, and what is the main flow. it is an issue of design and for that I need to see how your entire project looks like. I suggest talking to the guy who originally wrote it / anyone nearby that can see the entire project, or - edit your question and add your project tree, and all the relevant code, I will try and have a look, but it is far better to have someone that is next to you do it.

Comment: I've added 2 links for you to look at and replace your code with.

Comment: I and my friend solve the problem. Como fizemos para editar sua resposta com o conteúdo correto?

Comment: I've edited your post with the correct syntax. Please accept!

Comment: Your edit has been rejected by 3 other Stackoverflow members before I looked at it, I'm glad your problem has been solved, this answer is meant to serve other people after you that will have a similar problem in the future. I saw what you wanted to change, and although it also corrects the issue, it is somewhat of bad design and shows lack of understanding in code design. Due to that, I will not change the answer, although it might be great for you, but it may be less great for the next guy. So in short - glad your issue is resolved, glad I could help, and welcome to Stackoverflow. ;)